# Keeping a list of items in 7 columns

Tags: css

I can't seem to figure out how would go about limiting a list of items to be in 7 columns. I am making a calendar, and therefore I need the list of days to stay stay under my weekdays.

My first row is in the calendar is a simply headlines for the weekdays.

```html
      <div class="weekdays">
        <div>Sun</div>
        <div>Mon</div>
        <div>Tue</div>
        <div>Wed</div>
        <div>Thu</div>
        <div>Fri</div>
        <div>Sat</div>
      </div>
```

Under that I have a  with a loop of all my  witch are days, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 31

Previously I had my calendar at a set width, and I defined the width of my li as 1/7th of that width. However, now I need the width to be responsive. Therefore I need a way to ensure 7 items per line, so it fits with the weekdays. I figure the easiest way to do this is with columns, however, I cannot seem to figure out how to work with columns. Would I be able to benefit from using a grid instead of a ul and be able to make columns that way?

Comment: Use a table would be the simple option.

Answer (score 0):

Actully it's pretty simple using css `columns` for that:

```css
.weekdays{
  columns: 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="weekdays">
  <div>Sun</div>
  <div>Mon</div>
  <div>Tue</div>
  <div>Wed</div>
  <div>Thu</div>
  <div>Fri</div>
  <div>Sat</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You would defently will be benefit from using grid no doubts, but you could acutally use the `calc()` function in css. for example you set your Calender on width `90vw` (Or any other responsive value) then you could set the width of your days to `calc(90vw/7)`

```css
.weekdays{

    display:flex;
    width:80vw;
}

.weekdays div{
    margin:5px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:calc(80vw/7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
         <div class="weekdays">
        <div>Sun</div>
        <div>Mon</div>
        <div>Tue</div>
        <div>Wed</div>
        <div>Thu</div>
        <div>Fri</div>
        <div>Sat</div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```